# dynamic drop down list values javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to populate my drop down list with dynamic values but the list remains empty in other words no option is shown Could someone help me !!!
here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/n6ahz/24/

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
var text="TEXT";
var n=0;
newdiv.innerHTML += "<br> Question " + (n) + " : " + text + " ? <br><br>";
var m = 0;

var options = '';
for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
 var val = "marwa" + j;
if (val) {
    m++;
    options += " <option value="+j+"> " + val + "</option>";
     }
 }
 newdiv.innerHTML += "<select name='single' id='single'>";
 newdiv.innerHTML += " "+options + " </select> ";

document.getElementById('results').appendChild(newdiv);​
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
newdiv.innerHTML += "<select name='single' id='single'>";
newdiv.innerHTML += " "+options + " </select> ";
```

try

```
newdiv.innerHTML += "<select name='single' id='single'> "+options + " </select> ";
```

I don't think adding HTML a bit at a time works because the browser will try to render it immediately.

Comment: Thank u :) the problem is solved !!! I didn't expect that it has to be in a single line .

Answer (score 4):

With `innerHTML`, the actual DOM gets updated everytime you make a change. So you can't reliably make piecemeal changes like you're doing. Create a variable like `var html` and save all your HTML updates into it, then set `element.innerHTML = html`.

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
var html = "";
var text="TEXT";
var n=0;
html += "<br> Question " + (n) + " : " + text + " ? <br><br>";
var m = 0;

var options = '';
for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
 var val = "marwa" + j;
 if (val) {
    m++;
    options += " <option value="+j+"> " + val + "</option>";
 }
}
html += "<select name='single' id='single'>";
html += " "+options + " </select> ";
newdiv.innerHTML = html;

document.getElementById('results').appendChild(newdiv);​
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting using a variable and commit changes just once. My answer would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
var text="TEXT";
var n=1;
newdiv.innerHTML += "<br> Question " + (n) + " : " + text + " ? <br><br>";
var m = 1;

var options = '';
for (var j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
     var val = "marwa" + j;
if (val) {
        m++;
        options += " <option value="+j+"> " + val + "</option>";
         }
    }
newdiv.innerHTML += "<select name='single' id='single'  "+options + " </select> ";

document.getElementById('results').appendChild(newdiv);​
```